# Significado de la expresión "van a ir a por todas"

Tags: vocabulario

I found the text below in the internet:

> Esto último todavía no está claro, y sin embargo el rally de los
> mercados continúa... Mientras tanto, tenemos una visión más clara.
> Sabemos más sobre el virus y sobre la eficacia de las diferentes
> opciones de abordarlo. Además, sabemos que, no sólo los bancos
> centrales sino también los gobiernos, «**van a ir a por todas**», con
> independencia de lo que eso implique a largo plazo.

Lo traduje al inglés y al portugués y ninguno de ellos parece tener sentido. También investigué un poco y encontré que esta expresión se usa con algunos significados que aparentemente no encajan aquí.

Además, ¿qué justifica el uso del "a" después de "ir"? No tiene ningún sentido para un hablante nativo de portugués.

Si diz "ellos van **a ir a Nueva York**" suena perfecto para usar el "a" before Nueva York. Pero si dices "ellos van **a ir a por ti**", y así lo he encontrado, el uso del "a" antes de "por ti" parece no tener sentido.

Lo correcto no sería simplemente decir: "ellos van **a ir por ti**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En general, te puede ser más útil buscar en la RAE que tratar de traducir literalmente una expresión a otro idioma. Que en inglés o en portugués cierta construcción carezca de sentido no implica que no lo tenga en español (y viceversa).

En este caso puntual, [la RAE nos dice](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/ir-por-agua-o-ir-por-agua):

> El uso de la secuencia de preposiciones *a por* tras verbos que indican
> movimiento, como *ir, venir, volver, salir*, etc., **con el sentido de ‘en
> busca de**’, es hoy normal en el español de España, donde es corriente
> decir *Ve a por agua, Salgo a por el pan, Volvió a por el paraguas*. En
> el español de América, en cambio, este uso se percibe como anómalo y
> sigue siendo general allí el empleo exclusivo, en estos casos, de la
> preposición por: *Ve por agua, Salgo por el pan, Volvió por el
> paraguas.*
>
> No hay razones lingüísticas para condenar el uso de *a por*, tan
> legítimo como el de otras combinaciones de preposiciones nunca
> censuradas, como *para con, de entre, por entre, tras de, de por,* etc.
> La secuencia *a por* (documentada ya en textos españoles de los siglos
> xvi y xvii) se explica por el cruce de las estructuras *ir a un lugar*
> (complemento de dirección) e *ir por algo o alguien* (‘en busca de’), ya
> que en esta última está también presente la idea de ‘movimiento
> hacia’.
>
> Por otra parte, el uso de ambas preposiciones, frente al empleo
> aislado de por, resuelve en muchos casos problemas de ambigüedad; así,
> la oración *Voy por mi hijo* puede significar ‘voy a buscar a mi hijo’,
> ‘voy en lugar de mi hijo’, ‘voy en favor o por el bien de mi hijo’ o
> ‘voy porque me lo ha pedido mi hijo’; mientras que la oración *Voy a
> por mi hijo* solo puede significar ‘voy a buscar a mi hijo’.